# best way to escape and create a slug

Tags: php, slug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL Friendly Username in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php)

im somehow confused in using proper functions to escape and create a slug

i used this :

```
$slug_title = mysql_real_escape_string()($mtitle);
```

but someone told me not to use it and use urlencode()

which one is better for slugs and security

as i can see in SO , it inserts - between words :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941270/validating-a-slug-in-django
```

Comment: View my answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string/10360316#10360316

Answer (score 12):

Using either MySQL or URL escaping is not the way to go.

[Here is an article](http://www.socialgeek.be/blog/read/clean-urls-through-readable-slugs-in-php) that does it better:

```
function toSlug($string,$space="-") {
    if (function_exists('iconv')) {
        $string = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
    }
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/", "", $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = str_replace(" ", $space, $string);
    return $string;
}
```

This also works correctly for accented characters.

Comment: problem is for arabic and mb languages this function wont work and changes all characters to -

Comment: Unfortunately iconv seems to work inconcistently across platforms: php -r 'print iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT","bär") . "\n";' gives 'bar' on Ubuntu (10.04) and 'b"ar' on my Mac.

Comment: Ah... PHP's platform independency... gotta love it.

Comment: Yes... Even not working with string like: markedsføring

Answer (score 2):

mysql_real_escape_string() has different purpose than urlencode() which both aren't appropriate for creating a slug.

A slug is supposed to be a **clear & meaningful** phrase that concisely describes the page.

mysql_real_escape_string() escapes dangerous characters that can change the purpose of the original query string.

urlencode() escapes invalid URL characters with "%" followed by 2 hex digits that represents their code (e.g. %20 for space). This way, the resulting string will **not** be **clear & meaningful**, because of the unpleasant characters sequences, e.g. http://www.domain.com/bad%20slug%20here%20%3C--

Thus any characters which may be affected by urlencode() should be omitted, except for spaces that are usually replaced with `-`.