# Java and SEO friendly URLs: ©reate ╨ a valid http URL from a string composed by special caracters

Tags: java, url, encoding, seo

I'm trying to extract SEO friendly URLs from strings that can contain special characters, letter with accents, Chinese like characters, etc. 
SO is doing this and it's translating this post title in

```
java-and-seo-friendly-urls-reate--a-valid-http-url-from-a-string-composed-by-s
```

I'm trying to do this in Java.
 
I'm using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from) solution with [URLEncoder.encode](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to translate Chinese and other symbols into valid URL characters.

Have you ever implemented something like this? Is there a better way?

Comment: This question has a regex based way to do it in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580581/best-way-to-escape-and-create-a-slug

Answer (score 3):

This might be an oversimplistic approach to the problem, but you could just use regular expressions to remove all non standard characters. So after converting your string to lowercase, you can replace all non lowercase alphabetic characters with an empty character and then replace all spaces with the '-' character.

```
private static String encodeForUrl(String input) {
  return input.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z\\s]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "-");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any standard way for this, I've been using a similair solution as what you are refering to. Not sure which one's better, so here you have it:

```
public class TextUtils {

private static final Pattern DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS =
        Pattern.compile("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");

private static final Transliterator TO_LATIN_TRANSLITERATOR = Transliterator.getInstance("Any-Latin");

private static final Pattern EEQUIVALENTS = Pattern.compile("[ǝƏ]+");
private static final Pattern IEQUIVALENTS = Pattern.compile("[ı]+");
private static final Pattern DEQUIVALENTS = Pattern.compile("[Ððđ]+");
private static final Pattern OEQUIVALENTS = Pattern.compile("[Øø]+");
private static final Pattern LEQUIVALENTS = Pattern.compile("[Ł]+");

//all spaces, non-ascii and punctuation characters except _ and -
private static final Pattern CRAP = Pattern.compile("[\\p{IsSpace}\\P{IsASCII}\\p{IsP}\\+&&[^_]]");
private static final Pattern SEPARATORS = Pattern.compile("[\\p{IsSpace}/`-]");

private static final Pattern URLFRIENDLY = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9_])*");
private static final CharsetEncoder ASCII_ENCODER = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder();

/**
 * Returns true when the input test contains only characters from the ASCII set, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isPureAscii(String text) {
    return ASCII_ENCODER.canEncode(text);
}

/**
 * Replaces all characters that normalize into two characters with their base symbol (e.g. ü -> u)
 */
public static String replaceCombiningDiacriticalMarks(String text) {
    return DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS.matcher(Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFKD)).replaceAll("");
}

/**
 * Turns the input string into a url friendly variant (containing only alphanumeric characters and '-' and '_'). 
 * If the input string cannot be converted an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.
 */
public static String urlFriendlyStrict(String unfriendlyString) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    String friendlyString =
            urlFriendly(unfriendlyString);

    //Assert can be removed to improve performance
    Assert.isTrue(URLFRIENDLY.matcher(friendlyString).matches(),
            format("Friendly string [%s] based on [%s] is not friendly enough", friendlyString, unfriendlyString));
    return friendlyString;
}

/**
 * Turns the input string into a url friendly variant (containing only alphanumeric characters and '-' and '_').
 * Use {@link #urlFriendlyStrict(String)} to avoid potential bugs in this code.
 */
private static String urlFriendly(String unfriendlyString) {
    return removeCrappyCharacters(
            replaceEquivalentsOfSymbols(
                    replaceCombiningDiacriticalMarks(
                            transLiterateSymbols(
                                    replaceSeparatorsWithUnderscores(
                                            unfriendlyString.trim()))))).toLowerCase();
}

private static String transLiterateSymbols(String incomprehensibleString) {
    String latin = TO_LATIN_TRANSLITERATOR.transform(incomprehensibleString);
    return latin;
}

private static String replaceEquivalentsOfSymbols(String unfriendlyString) {
    return
            LEQUIVALENTS.matcher(
                    OEQUIVALENTS.matcher(
                            DEQUIVALENTS.matcher(
                                    IEQUIVALENTS.matcher(
                                            EEQUIVALENTS.matcher(unfriendlyString).replaceAll("e"))
                                            .replaceAll("i"))
                                    .replaceAll("d"))
                            .replaceAll("o"))
                    .replaceAll("l");
}

private static String removeCrappyCharacters(String unfriendlyString) {
    return CRAP.matcher(unfriendlyString).replaceAll("");
}

private static String replaceSeparatorsWithUnderscores(String unfriendlyString) {
    return SEPARATORS.matcher(unfriendlyString).replaceAll("_");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I would say URLEncoder.encode is the way to go. All non-URL chars are mapped, and you surely don't want to reinvent the wheel (again and again and again).

Comment: Yes, but encoding characters is the last-step (after cleaning String accents etc) in order to obtain a valid URL. Encoded chars are not SEO friendly... do not perform well in searches.